# Approve a single token ID in ERC1155 token standard

Tags: etherscan, nft, erc-721, ethereumjs, erc-1155

I am facing an issue when i am trying to give approval to the operator to burn my token in ERC1155. The issue is i want only to give access to the particular token id with a particular amount. But ERC1155 standard gives only one method i.e setApprovalForAll() which allow operator to access all my assets.

```
function _setApprovalForAll(
        address owner,
        address operator,
        bool approved
) internal virtual {
        require(owner != operator, "ERC1155: setting approval status for self");
        _operatorApprovals[owner][operator] = approved;
        emit ApprovalForAll(owner, operator, approved);
}
```

I just want to give him access for particular token ID like ERC721 approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) method gives to us.

```
/**
* @dev See {IERC721-approve}.
*/
function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual override {
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(to != owner, "ERC721: approval to current owner");

        require(
            _msgSender() == owner || isApprovedForAll(owner, _msgSender()),
            "ERC721: approve caller is not owner nor approved for all"
        );

        _approve(to, tokenId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I think you should create ERC721 contract cause IERC1155 doesn't have any core approve() function . It only consists of a setapprovalfor all() function.
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155